# How do I homogenise a small pellet of 10 to 50 cells within less than 50 µL?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, lab-techniques, methods, prokaryotic-cells

I have a problem with declumping/ homogenising bacterial cells in small volumes (10 to 50 µL). I know that I can get all of my cells out of the tube, but they are still stuck together and won't form separate colonies on an agar dish.
I know that because when I take the last 50 µl from a 1 ml tube and put it in a new tube and mix the 50 µL with a larger volume (e.g. 100 µL), we get a higher CFU count.

Comment: Just to be sure: is it really 10-50 cells in your pellet? Or is this a typo and its rather 10-50 x 10^6 cells  or similar?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Yes, there are only 10 to 50 colony building units in the 50 µL pellet!

Comment: What homogenisation method(s) did you already try?